# Django AbstractBaseUser Authentication-Login

Tags: python, django, django-authentication

> this is my views.py file

```
def user_login(request):
if request.method == 'POST':    
    username = request.POST['username']
    password = request.POST['password']
    

    user = auth.authenticate(username=username, password=password)               

    if user is not None:
        auth.login(request, user)
        
        return redirect('user_home_url')

    else:
        messages.info(request, 'invalid username and password')
        return redirect('user_login_url')
```

> models.py

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
"""Database Model for storing users profile"""
first_name = models.CharField(max_length = 15)
last_name = models.CharField(max_length = 15)
email = models.EmailField(max_length = 35, unique = True)
username = models.CharField(max_length = 35, unique = True)
is_active = models.BooleanField(default = False)
is_staff = models.BooleanField(default = False)
password = models.CharField(max_length = 25)
phone = models.CharField(max_length = 13, null = False, blank = False, unique = True)
phone_verified = models.BooleanField(default = False)
otp = models.IntegerField(null = True)

objects = UserProfileManager()

USERNAME_FIELD='username'
REQUIRED_FIELDS=['password','email','phone','first_name','last_name']


def get_full_name(self):
    """return full name of user"""
    return self.first_name + self.last_name

def __str__(self):
    """return string representation of user"""
    return self.email
```

settings.py

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'Users.User'
```

> Tried different methods using authenticate method but always getting invalid username and password

```
def user_login(request):
if request.method == 'POST':    
    username = request.POST['username']
    password = request.POST['password']
    users = User.objects.all()
    
    for user in users:
        if user.email == email and user.password == password:
          return redirect('user_home_url')
```

> when I use this code in views.py instead of "authenticate" method it's working perfectly but the problem is then I am not able to use @login_required

> Sorry for asking stupid questions like this, I am a noobie, and this is my first question

Answer (score 0):

This will never work as the password is NOT saved as plain text in the database, so you can't compare the received password with the saved one

The easiest way is

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate
def user_login(request):
     if request.method == 'POST':    
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = auth.authenticate(username = username, password=password)
        if user:     # as None means wrong username/password
           authenticate.login(request,user)
           return redirect('user_home_url')
        return HttpResponse("Wrong Username/Password")
```

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that when you compare the submitted password with the `user.password`, it is "working perfectly". This indicates that you have stored passwords in the database as plain text.

You really need to get in the habit of hashing passwords. Django can take care of this for you, as the `AbstractBaseUser` has a `set_password` method:

```py
# Set a password manually
user.set_password('newpassword')
```

Once you have the passwords saved appropriately, the `auth.authenticate` method should do what you expect.

If you are interested in password hashing, the Django docs have a great page on [password management](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/auth/passwords/).